# How to organize files in the Rails 5.2 assets pipeline?

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I understand how the asset pipeline takes the files stated in the manifest and preprocesses the files, concatenates them into one file and then compresses the file for faster downloads.

In my application I have a few distinct sections where there are different dependencies.

In my assets I have created three directories for these three sections:

```
stylesheets
  application.scss  -manifest for common elements such as bootstrap

  proofreaders
   index.scss  -manifest file for this section
   p_dashboard.scss

  clients
   index.scss -manifest file for this section
   c_dashboard.scss

  frontend
    index.scss -manifest file for this section
    custom.scss
```

I have added the files to my config/initializeres/assets.rb file:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(proofreaders/index.css clients/index.scss frontend/index.scss)
```

Here is a sample of what is in my application.scss manifest file:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "fonts";
@import "variables";
@import "utilities";
@import "bootstrap-overrides";
@import "animations";
@import "custom";
```

In my proofreaders layout file I have the following:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta content=("text/html; charset=UTF-8") http-equiv="Content-Type" /
    title Dashboard
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = stylesheet_link_tag  'application', 'proofreaders', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

The idea is that when the user first enters the site via the frontend section they will download the application.css compressed file and the frontend.css compressed file.

Then if they proceed to another section, say the Proofreaders section, since they already have downloaded the application.css file they should have it cached and therefore do not need to download it again.

So my question is do I have this understanding correct in the way I have organized my files and the way the browser/server will work to minimize downloads?

If not, is there anyway to minimize the downloading of files if the user has already downloaded them via a previous section?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding seems correct. As i am getting here you are creating 3 more manifest files and loading application in all the layouts/sections so your application.css file should get downloaded when user enters the site from first section/layout and it should not send request again.

Although You can confirm your environment assets configuration like assets debug and compile mode or cache should not be null_store.

or If everything seems fine then you can check the browser settings cache also. Like in chrome you can press CTRL + SHIFT + I and then in network menu check the disabled cache option.

Hope you get some help with this.

Comment: just so I understand you correctly, once the user enters the site and downloads the application.css file the first time, they should have it cached at that point. So then when they enter another section of the website even though the application.css file is part of the layout they won't download it again and just used the cached version?

Comment: Yes. It should use the same cached version. To check its working or not you can press `CTRL + SHIFT + I` in crome and In the network menu the size column of application.css request should show from cache.